# Usage of decltype in function parameters

Tags: c++, c++11, coding-style

This seems to be kinda common approach today

```
auto foo(T a, K b) -> dectlype(a+b);
```

But what of this code?

```
void foo(decltype(a));
```

in there "a" is a type of a variable in some class. like:

```
class SomeClass
{
    public:
    void foo(decltype(a)); 
    private: 
    int a;
};
```

Now, I understand that oldstyle approach is to use typedef:

```
typedef int IntType;
```

But what of decltype? What do you think?

As I see it - this has these disadvantages:

1. can't be used in abstract interfaces (there is no "a" to take type
   of)
2. makes code harder to read
3. most common IDE's don't generate
   correct definitions for decltyped functions

A single pro I can think of:

1. you are safe against type changes without ever having to change typedef.

Tbh, I think that cons far outweigh such usage of decltype but I want to hear opinions other than mine :)

Comment: What is the objective? To ensure the function argument type remains exactly that of the type of `a`?

Comment: Yep. That's what it is about

Comment: "most common IDE's don't generate correct definitions for decltyped functions" erm what

Comment: @Zeks Than write a template function `template<typename T> void foo(T);`. This is far easier on the eyes and is basically the same thing.

Comment: @arne Except templates are not combinable with, say Q_OBJECT :)

Comment: @Zeks: But that's a MAJOR shortcoming of Qt. I'm not entirely sure though that your `decltype` trick will work, either.

Comment: @R. Martinho Fernandes if you try "Refactor->add definition" in QtCreator it will fail miserably if a parameter is decltype

Comment: @Zeks: Does _QtCreator_ fit the definition of "most common IDE's _[sic]_"? No, not really. It's just one IDE, for a start.

Answer (score 2):

I don't want my API to change because I changed the type of some variable and forgot about the repercussions.

If I do that, I want a compilation error.

Let it be so.

Comment: Like I said - I do not think decltype is a good idea :) And comments so far make me believe I was indeed correct and it's not supposed to be used like that.

Comment: @Zeks: Yep, I'd say so. It can be useful for _trailing return types_ and in, say, templates. But other than that I'd give it a miss.